# lumen observer is not working on the eloquent model

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am using lumen 5.5. I am trying to make the observer called on while updating/deleting the model. When i tried that with user model, observer is not calling. When i did that with the events everything works fine. It's not even shows any errors.

Here is my code:

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
....
use App\Models\User;
use App\Observers\UserObserver;
...

public function boot() {
    User::observe(UserObserver::class);

}
```

**App\Models\User.php**

```
...
    public static function changeCustomerStatus(int $customerID): int{
        $customer = self::where([
                'id'        => $customerID,
                'user_type' => app('config')->get('user_type.CUSTOMER')
            ])
            ->first();

        if ($customer) {
            $customer->status = $customer->status == app('config')->get('status.ACTIVE') ? app('config')->get('status.DEACTIVE') : app('config')->get('status.ACTIVE');

            if ($customer->save()) {
                return $customer->status;
            }

            return 0;
        }   
        else 
            return 0;
    }
...
```

**App\Observers\UserObserver.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Models\User;

class UserObserver {

    public function updated(User $user) {
        if ($user->status === app('config')->get('status.DEACTIVE')) {
            app('log')->info('updated');
        }
    }


public function saved(User $user) {
        if ($user->status === app('config')->get('status.DEACTIVE')) {
            app('log')->info('saved');
        }
    }


    public function deleted(User $user) {
        app('log')->info('deleted');
    }
}
```

I even did the `composer dump-autoload`. But no luck

Comment: This [Article](https://medium.com/@dneey/bringing-laravel-model-observers-to-lumen-6916a16cb76b) explain how to bring laravel Observers to lumen. I test it using lumen 8.x and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lumen doesn't have observe feature. 
You can use Events instead or make custom observer and call its functions from your code.

Read docs here - [Events](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/6.x/events)

Comment: Thanks. That's the doubt i had. In the lumen documentation nowhere its mentioned. And also its not even triggered any errors

Comment: Yes, I knew it but searched in source and nothing found: https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/search?q=observe&type=Code 
https://github.com/laravel/lumen/search?q=observe&unscoped_q=observe&type=Code

Answer (score 2):

Lumen does not have model observers the way Laravel does. I agree with using events or implementing your custom observers. If you choose to go with the latter, here is a post that might help.
https://link.medium.com/ZHsJwJuvC5